# Retrieving Payment Gateway from Transaction API of Shopify

Tags: shopify

We have an web hook being enabled on "Order Creation" event. The json response which we used to receive earlier gave a parameter "gateway" holding information about payment gateway being chosen by customer. But now for orders being created from last Friday 24th April 2015, we are not getting this parameter, instead we are getting a parameter "financial status" with value "pending". We need this payment gateway Method ex. "Paypal", "COD", "Bank Transfer", as we display this on on invoice being printed.

Suggestion from shopify team says "gateway" field is now deprecated in "Order Creation" and we should use now following link to fetch it. https://spskids.myshopify.com/admin/orders/315026241/transactions.json

We created an another webhook for payment gateway on "Order Payment" event and trying to call it from my 3rdy party website.

But issue is we want to call this from a third party website, When I do so it gives an error of unauthorized access. Please suggest how to fetch payment gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Gateway parameter has recently been moved to transactions. And, transactions are not yet ready to be used with webhooks: https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks

You should get the payment gateway by storing transaction resource on your end.

Comment: How can I get payment gateway by storing transaction resource on my end as this was being returned in the json from Shopify ? There is no other means to get transaction payment gateway of customer except this.

Comment: @DevanshuKumar You grab this: https://docs.shopify.com/api/transaction and store "gateway" object

Comment: I checked that but the issue is data flows from shopify to my site. When I am trying to consume this transaction api from my server, I receive an authorised access. I am not getting a way out to consume this api from my server. I created an app an using this app secret and client id too for making a call. But the result is same "Un authorized access". How to handle this?

Comment: @DevanshuKumar use te Shopify API gem